# All terminal commands (like ls, cd, edit, open) are returning errors on my Mac

Tags: terminal.app, ruby, .bash-profile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do I reset the $PATH variable on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/121870/how-do-i-reset-the-path-variable-on-mac-os-x)

From what I can tell from reading other questions/answers is that my .bash_profile file may be corrupt. If I type

> echo $PATH

in terminal the result is:

> /usr/local/git/bin

From what I've read, that's not what the result is supposed to be. But I also can't get any of the commands (like edit or subl, for Sublime Text 2) to open the .bash_profile file to edit it. I was able to open the file in TextEdit using "cmd-shift-.", and here's what's in the file:

> [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
>
> PATH=$PATH:~/bin
>
> export PATH
>
> export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin

But the file is LOCKED, so I can't edit it there either. I'm very new to programming and in the middle of trying to install everything on my Mac to go through a Ruby on Rails tutorial. I can't even check my version of ruby, since even

> ruby -v

returns

> -bash: ruby: command not found

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Adjust your question title because I'm pretty sure `cd` is working (is a shell built-in and needs no PATH)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Temporarily fix the `PATH`, directly in the broken shell:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

(This is my `PATH`, it should mostly work for you as well)

---

Give yourself write permissions for that file, with or without fixing `PATH` as above:

```
/usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod u+rwx /Users/yourusername/.bash_profile
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown yourusername /Users/yourusername/.bash_profile
```

Fix the `PATH` assignment in the last line to:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
```

Close your shell, and open a new one.

Comment: Sorry for such a basic question, but what exactly do you mean by "shell"? Is that the same thing as my running Terminal window?

Comment: @park Shell is the software running within a Terminal window and tab that interprets your commands. In your case, it's called `bash`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. The temporary fix worked in that shell to get commands like 'ls' working again (but not in a separate shell, so I guess that's why you called it temporary).

For a permanent fix, is that where the next two lines of code you posted come in? The ones beginning with '/usr/bin/sudo'? I've heard that using 'sudo' you have to be very careful, and since I'm new to this I'm worried about messing something up. Should I just run those as two separate commands in Terminal?

And finally, is the last line something I run as a 'export' command in terminal, or add to the .bash_profile txt file?

Comment: @park Yes, after replacing the placeholder (`yourusername` appropriate). They'll make you the owner of that file and give yourself all permissions, since you mentioned it was "locked". After you can edit `.bash_profile`, change the last line to what I posted. This will no longer reset your `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have worked and even `subl` works again to open text files in Sublime Text2. I just wish I knew how I messed up .bash_profile in the first place.

Comment: @park By installing git, from what it looks like :-)

Comment: Maybe :) I'm doing a ROR tutorial and installed git a while ago. The errors began during the Heroku setup portion of the tutorial which is a while after the git setup. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know if this will help but try:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

I'm also running mac and that is what occurs when i type `echo $PATH` which means you probably need these functions in terminal.

Comment: He's in `bash`, and that's not `bash` syntax.

Comment: I knew he was in bash my mistake to forget to remove the `$` but without the `$` it would work

Answer (score 0):

i think you can try [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/121870/how-do-i-reset-the-path-variable-on-mac-os-x) to reset your $PATH! close the current terminal and start new one to make sure the changed settings are loaded!

Comment: If your answer entirely consists of a link to another question, then that's a good indicator this question should be closed as a duplicate of the other.