# Command not found on (Terminal) iMac

Tags: macos, bash, terminal.app, imac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reset the $PATH variable on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/121870/how-do-i-reset-the-path-variable-on-mac-os-x)

When I open terminal and type the `ls` command, it says:

```
command not found.
```

I found a [link](https://superuser.com/questions/374204/all-commands-are-not-working-on-mac-os-x-lion) that resolves the problem, but only temporarily. When I exit the terminal and then re-login I have to follow this procedure again.

Is there a permanent solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check `~/.profile` and `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` to make sure you haven't replaced `$PATH` by accident. Any lines that set `PATH` should also add the old `$PATH` at either the beginning or the end.

Comment: Hi nneonneo, How can I open ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist file. I may able to open .profile file with the following command open -e .profile

Comment: If it doesn't exist, then it won't affect you.